# How to post a form at external url in cake php.?

Tags: cakephp, paypal

I am going to implement paypal in cake php. I have two conditions to post the form.

1. Fist posts the form to paypal, if user click on paypal button. Then form shoud be posted at paypal url at : https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr .
2. If user click on submit button form should be posted to it controller.

It means i want to create two forms at a single page and want to posts at different places in certain conditions.

If I am giving custom action in form, it is adding app name+controller name before the url. like: `appname/controllername/http://google.com`. but want only `http://google.com` .I want to remove `appname/controllername` from the url.

How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In your form creation call, you need to specify the URL

```
echo $this->Form->create('Model', array('url' => 'http://google.com'));
```

Comment: @Dinesh you might consider marking this answer as accepted. You should also do the same with the rest of your questions